# Flickity JS carousel plus nav slider

Tags: javascript

This is meant to present main content in the carousel above with a painless navigation below where the moment you start dragging the content keeps up.

I was trying to avoid having to drag once per slide or press "next" many times. Also the `previous` and `next` classes are added for effect. Will look quite different in production, it's the functionality I'm showing off here.

Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/Julix/pen/xexawP

```js
// Flickity slider from external js: flickity.pkgd.js
// Prev- and next classes from external js: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wWQQwN.js 
"use strict";

var $carousel = $('.carousel-main').flickity({
  "wrapAround": true,
  "draggable": true,
  "prevNextButtons": false,
  "pageDots": false
});
var $nav = $('.carousel-nav').flickity({
  "on": {
    ready: choseCenterSlide,
    scroll: choseCenterSlide
  },
  "asNavFor": ".carousel-main",
  "wrapAround": true,
  "percentPosition": false,
  "draggable": true,
  "pageDots": false,
  "prevNextButtons": false
});
;
var navDragging = false;
$nav.on('dragStart.flickity', function () {
  return navDragging = true;
});
$nav.on('settle.flickity', function () {
  return navDragging = false;
});
$nav.data('flickity').resize();

var isWrapped = true;
var isInstant = true;
function choseCenterSlide() {
  // check if this.x is within slideableWidth
  var currentX = this.x > 0 ? -this.slideableWidth + this.x : this.x < -this.slideableWidth ? this.slideableWidth + this.x : this.x; // calculate closest slide

  var distances = this.slides.map(function (slide) {
    return -slide.target;
  });
  var closestDistance = distances.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return Math.abs(curr - currentX) < Math.abs(prev - currentX) ? curr : prev;
  });
  var closestSlideIndex = distances.indexOf(closestDistance); // early return

  if (closestSlideIndex == this.scrollSlideIndex) return; // register 

  if (this.scrollSlideIndex == null) this.scrollSlideIndex = this.selectedIndex; // change scrollSlide

  this.slides[this.scrollSlideIndex].cells.forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.element.classList.remove('is-closest');
  });
  this.slides[closestSlideIndex].cells.forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.element.classList.add('is-closest');
  }); // update state variable

  this.scrollSlideIndex = closestSlideIndex; // update selectedSlide

  if (navDragging) {
    this.select(this.scrollSlideIndex, isWrapped, isInstant);

    if (this.navCompanion) {
      this.navCompanion.select(this.scrollSlideIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* external css: flickity.css */


.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-selected {
  background: lightblue;
}
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-closest {
  background: #ffd466;
}

.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-closest {
  background: #ffd466;
}
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-selected {
  background: lightblue;
}

.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-nav-selected {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, darkred, #640404, darkred);
}
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-previous {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, darkred, lightgreen);
}
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell.is-next {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkred, lightgreen);
}



* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: transparent;
}

.carousel-main .carousel-cell,
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell {
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: carousel-cell;
}


.carousel-main .carousel-cell {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    width: 66%;
}
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell {
  width: 300px;
}

/* cell number */
.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(carousel-cell);
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}


.carousel-nav {
  
}
.carousel-nav .carousel-cell {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wWQQwN.js"></script>


<h1>Main attraction</h1>
<div class="carousel carousel-main">
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>

<h2>Navigation</h2>

<div class="carousel carousel-nav">
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

Feedback welcome! :)